# Showing hashed password for a public URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, hash, passwords

So I have web application running. I am using ion_auth for my authentication. All good there. 
But I am making a feature where the user can share some part of his info to some other people who won't need to to registered on the application. Basically a public URL. So it is (unguessable) secure as i have hashed out link with salt as in `localhost/test/view/ajbfsefhufwufwf....dsfjIUy4hdsfsf..64 chars`
Now I thinking that the information might be a bit sensative, I might as well set a simple **auto or user** generated password on before showing that info. So that way only the user with url and password can view that info shared by the registered user. 
I would like to hash the paswword. But since it hashed no way to retrieve it.
So the problem is, how do I show the user that is sharing the link that hey, you can use this public link with this password? He needs to be able to view the password later on as well so storing the password in local variable to show it momentarily is not an option.

Comment: Generally only a *nonce* would be in the URL and the password-auth stored (and verified, using appropriate password management techniques) on the server.

Comment: In any case the point of password hashing is that it *can't* be retrieved; the user must supply a (the) password that hashes to the expected value. This could be embedded into the URL itself as a separate parameter; if really wishing to go this route, look up HMAC (to verify that the 'password hash' portion of the URL matches the requested resource).

Comment: Hello, Yes the password is stored and authenticated on server. The problem is how to show the user who is sending the link to another user the password that was auto generated(if it were to be hashed)

Comment: Have the user *choose* a password and *tell* the other party. If you want to 'automatically' tell someone a password on a users behalf (in which case it really just becomes a 'shared secret') then you must store it in a reversible manner. That's all there is to it; you may want to look into encryption over the stored passwords, but at that point the rabbit is really out of the hat.

Comment: (The encryption *might* require a passphrase - or otherwise include the account/session information as part of the key - that the 'owner' would have to enter in whenever sending an email/link; this would recover the PT password, but auth would still be vs a hash.)

Comment: The actual question is, how do you want to share the password with the external user? If you send this password with the mail containing the URL, then you could simply create a new password, store its hash (together with the token) and send the generated password to the external user.

Comment: encrypting password, might do the trick. Also the email idea is good. But what happens if I want to resend the link to another user. It is the same loop again

Comment: @neelabh - Storing encrypted passwords is much less safe than storing only password hashes. Wouldn't it be an advantage if every external user would get its own password? The same password could be sent to groups to, and they can be deactivated if necessary.

Comment: well then i would need to store all the passwords that map to a document in an in-between table. id---docid(FK)---hash. Am I missing something?

Comment: @neelabh - Yes that's what i would recommend anyway, keeping the documents in one table and the user credentials (docid-token-passwordhash) in another table.